# Latest version of socket io nodejs is not connecting to flutter applications

Tags: node.js, flutter, socket.io, real-time

Currently, I am trying to use sockets with flutter application which works fine when I use version ^2.3.0. But when I tried using the latest version of socket io in nodejs i.e. 4.1.2, it didn't while it's still working with a browser.
I am unable to figure out what's happening.

I am sharing the code for the flutter socket io connection as well as the nodejs application.

```
import 'package:getparked/Utils/DomainUtils.dart';
import 'package:socket_io_client/socket_io_client.dart' as IO;

class SocketUtils {
  IO.Socket socketIO;

  IO.Socket init(onSocketConnected, onSocketDisconnected) {
    socketIO = IO.io(domainName, <String, dynamic>{
      'transports': ['websocket'],
      'upgrade': false
    });

    socketIO.connect();
    socketIO.on("connect", (data) {
      print("Connection Successfully Established...");
      onSocketConnected(socketIO);
    });

    socketIO.on("reconnect", (data) {
      print("Socket Connected Again.. Reconnection");
    });

    socketIO.on("disconnect", (data) {
      print("Socket Disconnected Unexpectedly..");
      onSocketDisconnected(socketIO);
    });

    return socketIO;
  }
}
```

Node js Code

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const server=require('http').createServer(app);
io = require('socket.io')(server, {
  cors:{
      origin:"*"
  },
});
io.on('connection', (socket) => { 
  console.log(socket.id);
});
server.listen(+port, () => {
  console.log("Server is running...");
  console.log(name + " " + port);
  vehicleUtils.init();
  adminUtils.init();
});
```

I anyone knows any way to fix this either in flutter or nodejs without downgrading the version please let me know.

Comment: Exactly same issue happening with me. Any progress ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all, found the exact solution a few days after I posted it here.
The problem is not with the backend or nodejs though it looks like a problem of the backend it isn't.
[image]

I was using this exact version of the socket io client which is not suitable for the later versions of socket io in nodejs for connections.

Then I came to know about this which I found in the documentation of the socket io client in the pub. dev.

[image]

Then I just changed the version rebuilt it and it worked.
Try changing the version of the socket io client in your Flutter app to 2.0 which will definitely solve your problem.

Comment: Thank ! I had the same issu and that solve it :-)

Comment: guys I tired using newer versions of the library but the latest one that I was able to add was 1.0.1 . How did updates to a later version ? @Benjamin

Comment: The latest version of the socket io client is socket_io_client: ^2.0.0-beta.4-nullsafety.0 but its in the prerelease mode.
https://pub.dev/packages/socket_io_client/versions/2.0.0-beta.4-nullsafety.0

You can use 1.0.1 as well but with that, you have to go with older versions of the older socket io on the server.

Comment: Thank you! You are a lifesaver, some would think they would emphasize such an important thing more!